# Autobahn websocket issue while running with twistd using tac file

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, autobahnws

I have a WebSocket server implemented using [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) WebSocket framework using twisted. WebSocket server runs fine when the program ran with python. But if I run this using twistd server runner by creating tac file as twisted service, I get the following error in server while any client try to establish connection and the handshake is failing.

`2015-12-08 07:17:56,022 - CRITICAL - twisted.publishToNewObserver() 154 Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 597, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1067, in doRead
    protocol = self.factory.buildProtocol(self._buildAddr(addr))
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/protocol.py", line 135, in buildProtocol
    p = self.protocol()
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 665, in __init__
    self.is_closed = txaio.create_future()
  File "/opt/nrgi-ws/nrgi-ws-virtual-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/txaio/_unframework.py", line 43, in _throw_usage_error
    "To use txaio, you must first select a framework "
exceptions.RuntimeError: To use txaio, you must first select a framework with .use_twisted() or .use_txaio()`

Answer (score 3):

I found the same problem today. 
You should downgrade txaio to version 1.1.0

Here is my pip list
autobahn (0.10.9)
autobahntestsuite (0.7.3)
Twisted (15.4.0)
txaio (1.1.0)
zope.interface (4.1.3)

Comment: Rare to find the answer that so easily fixes a problem I am having. ran: pip install -U txaio==1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with Autobahn master? This should be fixed there, but there isn't yet a release containing the fix (dd1cff8f9480a125e510108482bfaf5b9eedc916).

You can install master like this: `pip install https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/archive/master.zip`

Answer (score 1):

AutobahnTestSuite was just updated and corrects this problem:

autobahn (0.10.9)
autobahntestsuite (0.7.4)
Twisted (15.5.0)
txaio (2.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not happening in my Ubuntu system. I was having this issue in ec2 instance with Machine Image Amazon Linux AMI. Seems txaio couldn’t detect the available twisted framework. Another fix other than mentioned above by @helder.vasc is to specify the framework as twisted explicitly.
Adding this below in tac file solved the issue :

`import txaio
txaio.use_twisted()`

Note sure about weather this is the perfect way to tackle this issue though.